# Custom ListView + SherlockFragment doesnt cooperate

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I use SherlockFragment Actionbars in my app, and inside one of the activities I have created a custom ListView. It seems that it doesnt work because of the Context, and im not sure how to get around it.

Here's my code from the Custom ListView:

```
package net.agnesium.lommebudsjett.view;

import java.util.List;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

import net.agnesium.lommebudsjett.R;
import net.agnesium.lommebudsjett.view.InnkjopActivity.ListViewItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListeKontroll extends BaseAdapter
{  

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ListViewItem> items;

    public ListeKontroll(Context context, List<ListViewItem> items) {  
        super();

        this.items = items;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }



    @Override  
    public int getCount() {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return items.size();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return null;  
    }  

    @Override  
    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return 0;  
    }

    @Override  
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        ListViewItem item = items.get(position);

        View vi=convertView;

        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.liste_rad, null);

        TextView imgThumbnail = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imgThumbnail);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView txtSubTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSubTitle);

        imgThumbnail.setText(item.navn);
        txtTitle.setText(item.pris);
        txtSubTitle.setText(item.kategori);

        return vi;  
    }
}
```

And the class where the ListView is put out:

```
package net.agnesium.lommebudsjett.view;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import net.agnesium.lommebudsjett.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class InnkjopActivity extends SherlockFragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_innkjop, container, false);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView kvittering = (ListView) V.findViewById(R.id.lstKvitt);
    List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        navn = "Produkt";
        pris = 100;
        kategori = "Kategori";

    }});

    ListeKontroll adapter = new ListeKontroll(this.getSherlockActivity(), items);
    kvittering.setAdapter(adapter);



    return V;


}
class ListViewItem{

    public int pris;
    public String navn;
    public String kategori;
}
```

}

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: If I use "ListeKontroll adapter = new ListeKontroll(this.getSherlockActivity(), items)", the app just crashes. And if I just use "new ListeKontroll(this, items)", I get "The constructor ListeKontroll(InnkjopActivity, List<InnkjopActivity.ListViewItem>) is undefined".

Comment: try doing `new ListeKontrol(getActivity(), items)`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_innkjop, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ListView kvittering = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.lstKvitt);
    List<ListViewItem> items = new ArrayList<ListViewItem>();
    items.add(new ListViewItem()
    {{
        navn = "Produkt";
        pris = 100;
        kategori = "Kategori";

    }});

    ListeKontroll adapter = new ListeKontroll(getActivity(), items);
    kvittering.setAdapter(adapter);

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```